# Uber API Price Estimates for Promotional/Experimental Product

Tags: uber-api

I understand that the Uber *Products* Endpoint (`GET /v1/products`) will not return experimental or promotional products such as UberPOOL and UberFRESH.

Does the *Price Estimate* Endpoint (`GET /v1/estimates/price`) return price estimates of those experimental/promotional products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the *Price Estimate* Endpoint returns price estimates including the experimental/promotional products. The [uber api documentation](https://developer.uber.com/v1/endpoints/) only states that the *products* endpoint does not include the experimental products.